# send 50 requests from spring scheduler each 1 second

Tags: java, spring, scheduled-tasks, scheduler, threadpoolexecutor

I have scheduler with method:

```
@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 1000L)
public void sendRequest() {           
 client.getData();   //send request to some server
}
```

Each second I need send 50 request(call `client.getData()`)
 How can I do it?

This example very bad, but I write it to show what I need:

```
@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 1000L)
public void sendRequest() {  
 for(int i=0; i<50; i++){         
 taskExecutor.execute(() -> client.getData());   //send request to some server
 }
}
```

Or maby I need create 50 `schedulers` and each scheduler will trigger each second?

Answer (score 0):

```
@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 1000L)
```

Processing of @Scheduled annotations is performed by registering a [ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.html). Bean post-processor that registers methods annotated with @Scheduled to be invoked by a [TaskScheduler](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/TaskScheduler.html) according to the "fixedRate", "fixedDelay", or "cron" expression provided via the annotation.
And here we have a concurrency story. If you use [ThreadPoolTaskScheduler](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/concurrent/ThreadPoolTaskScheduler.html) as the TaskScheduler implementation, literally, you have implementation of Spring's TaskScheduler interface, wrapping a native [ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html?is-external=true). Step by step we come to [Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html)s. They do require CPU time. CPU time is about your machine and it's configuration.

You can use this annotation for your purpose, but real performance depends on your machine, where the app's deployed. If machine's configuration (CPU and so on) provides ability to process/send 50 requests exactly every second - you're welcome. If you try to launch 50 schedulers as standalone apps on different computers it may also solve your problem.